# Saving NSDictionary to plist: Serialization error

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary with nested dictionaries (as per "flash cards") in my application. For some reason, the NSDictionary will not write to file. If I simply call writeToFile on my dictionary, it doesn't work, and NSPropertyListSerialization returns Property List invalid for Format. The code is as follows:

```
#import "flashCard.h"

#define kFront @"front"
#define kBack @"back"

@implementation flashCard

- (id) init
{
if (self = [super init])
{
    cards = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
             [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"aetas/aetatis", kFront,
              @"lifetime, age, generation", kBack,
              nil], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],
             [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"amicitia/amicitiae", kFront,
              @"alliance, friendship", kBack,
              nil], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
             [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"amicus/amici", kFront,
              @"friend", kBack,
              nil], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 3],
             [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"animus/animi", kFront,
              @"mind, heart, spirit, courage", kBack,
              nil], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 4],
             nil];

    currentSide = [[NSString alloc] init];

    currentCard = 1;
    currentSide = kFront;
}

return self;
}
```

later, in the same implementation...

```
- (void) saveSet
{
NSLog(@"saveSet called");
NSSavePanel *cocaoSavePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

int buttonPressed = [cocaoSavePanel runModal];
if (buttonPressed != NSOKButton)
{
    return;
}

NSLog(@"ok button, with url: %@", [cocaoSavePanel URL]);

NSError *error;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:cards
                     format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                    options: 0
                     error: &error];

if (plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToURL:[cocaoSavePanel URL] atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"File Saved Successfully");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: after revisions:

```
2011-08-12 13:00:47.937 flashcards[14452:a0f] saveSet called
2011-08-12 13:00:48.763 flashcards[14452:a0f] ok button, with url: file://localhost/Users/sam/Desktop/asdf
2011-08-12 13:00:48.764 flashcards[14452:a0f] {
    3 =     {
        back = friend;
        front = "amicus/amici";
    };
    2 =     {
        back = "alliance, friendship";
        front = "amicitia/amicitiae";
    };
    1 =     {
        back = "lifetime, age, generation";
        front = "aetas/aetatis";
    };
    4 =     {
        back = "mind, heart, spirit, courage";
        front = "animus/animi";
    };
}
2011-08-12 13:00:48.764 flashcards[14452:a0f] Property list invalid for format: 100
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but dont do this `currentSide = [[NSString alloc] init];` your just creating a memory leak in non garbage collecting environments when you reassign it later.

Comment: What does the error object tell you?

Comment: **Important: This method is obsolete and will be deprecated soon. Use dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error: instead.** ---- This other method also returns an NSError object which may contain more helpful information for tracking the problem down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
currentSide = [[NSString alloc] init];

currentCard = 1;
currentSide = kFront;
```

That leaks the empty `NSString` (or, would, but that `[[NSString alloc] init]` returns a singleton coincidentally).   Also, you are leaking all of the dictionaries that you put into the outer `cards` dictionary.

Generally, when this kind of error pops up, it is because you have a non-plist-compatible object in your dictionaries/arrays;  something that isn't an NSNumber, NSArray, NSDate, NSData, NSString, NSDictionary, etc....

`NSLog(@"%@", cards);` right before serialization and post that.   Also what is the exact plist serialization format error?

---

I just copy/pasted your code and got:

```
asdfasdf[81731:707] Property list invalid for format (property list dictionaries may only have keys which are CFStrings, not 'CFNumber')
```

- you can't have keys that are numbers
- always read and post the entirety of the error messages spewed at runtime

Comment: friend isn't a string (see my edit above), which I don't understand because when the dictionary is defined it is.

Comment: `friend` is still a string; the quotes are optional and not shown for strings without punctuation / spaces.

Comment: then I see no reason for the nsdictionary not to serialize.

Comment: Sorry. I posted all the error message I received and I'm extremely confused why it told you that and not me. If it had shown me that I wouldn't have posted the question on here in the first place.

Sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: No worries -- I admit to embracing my cranky pants a bit too vociferously.   If you have a moment, try making a minimal example and seeing if it produces the error message in a desktop runtime tool project vs. on the device.   It may be a difference in runtime behavior.  A bug complaining about the lack of a descriptive error message would be warranted.